# How to get the properties which is the same as using console.log(obj)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get an object by using mongoose, called `doc`.On 1console.log(doc)1, there is one property `owner:{}`, but if using `doc.toJSON()` or `doc.toObject()`, this property is disappeared, how can get this property. I can't use `for(p in o)`, because there are many unexpected properties, are there any other approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, mongoose removes empty objects when calling `toObject` or `toJSON`:

```
var doc = User({
   name:  "SomeUser"
   owner: {}, // empty object
});

doc.toObject(); // {name: "someUser"}
```

Pass the option [`minimize`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/21f16c62e2f3230fe616745a40f22b4385a11b11/lib/document.js#L1463) to disable this:

```
doc.toObject({minimize: false}); // {name: "someUser", owner: {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the native method:

```
JSON.stringify(doc)
```